# Angular 6 Material - Await until Mat Dialog is closed

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, angular-material, angular6

I have a list of actions to be done, if the boolean promptRequired is set, I show a dialog and based its value do some action.

Problem here is the for loop runs in parallel and all actions are executed simultaneously, but  I want the for loop to run synchronously and the loop must wait until the dialog is closed. Is there a solution?

```
async runActions() {
 for (const action of Actions) {
      if(action.promptRequired) {
      const dialogRef = this.promptDialog.open(PromptDialogComponent, {
        data: {action: action,
        },
      });
      // await dialogRef.afterClosed();
     }
    }

     const status =  await this.httpService.getRequest('runAction', action)
     // Do Some Action based on status
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Again, [read the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples). You even wrote the answer yourself ...

Comment: await for dialog close doesnt work, the next iteration doesnt wait until the dialog is closed

Comment: Then please, provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtpyr7

Comment: The issue isn't with the dialog, it's with your code. I really suggest you read [the documentation of await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and [the documentation of the dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) : one handles promises, the other observables.

Comment: I understand that you are trying to make me learn by myself, I am in a bit of urgency to complete this and hence, Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just turn the `afterClosed` Observable into a promise and await the result. Example:

```js
async runActions() {
  for (const action of Actions) {
    if(action.promptRequired) {
      const dialogRef = this.promptDialog.open(PromptDialogComponent, {
        data: {action: action },
      });

      await dialogRef.afterClosed().toPromise();
    }
  }

  const status =  await this.httpService.getRequest('runAction', action)
  // Do Some Action based on status
}
```

Comment: What about ngx-bootstrap? I'm quite stuck with that.

Comment: It's saying "afterClosed" is not in Subscribe